# How best to design database structure for this case?

Tags: database, database-design, data-structures, relational-database, entity-relationship

I'm designing a database for my University applications. There's **Report** entity of which is the following:

[image]

Each `report` has a list of `students`,  `courses` and students `rating` on them.

The problem is that over time, courses and number of students may change. The database structure should be flexible and easily adaptable to these changes. How best to define the relationships between these entities and design tables in a relational database for this case?

I have some thoughts on the matter. Perhaps this model best describes the relationship and solves problem of the issue:[image]

Or is the relationship `REPORT to STUDENT` superfluous and redundant? Is there enough of one relationship for a REPORT? For example only `REPORT to COURSE` without 
`REPORT to STUDENT`:[image]
Which choice is better and why? Does this structure have any other disadvantages?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: Can student belong to more than one report? Ditto for course?

Comment: Is it ever possible for a student **not** to belong to a report, even though student's course does belong to the report?

Comment: @Branko Thanks for your questions! First, yes, student and course can belong to more than one report. Because report may be different. Yearly report, monthly report, weekly report, lessons report...
Second, a student belongs to a report. Report has report and course property and they must both belong to the same report. But we can retrieve report to the student through rating and course (`report to rating`, `rating to course`, `course to report`), can't we? So we will not have data redundancy. What do you think about this? It's not very well? Thanks for advance!

Comment: _"student and course can belong to more than one report"_ - Then neither schema is correct. On the face value of it, you'll need a junction table between REPORT and COURSE (and possibly for students as well). I'm still unclear about what "report" actually means. Is this an assessment by the student that took the course about the quality of the course (and/or lecturer)? Or is it the mark (or "progress assessment") that student earned for various parts of the course? Is it fair to say the report is a set of ratings?

Comment: _"the report is a set of ratings?"_ Yes, I can say that it is true. I should to persist the report. It's key entity in my application. Report also has number, title, date, approver, description, ect. I don't need the entity of lecturer. I abstracted from it. You can consider that my courses are self study :)

Comment: In other words the question is does an entity (any, e.g. Report) need have relationships with both entities between which a many-to-many relantionship (e.g. Student and Course) or only one entity from them (e.g. Student or Course)?

Comment: Of course class Report will have two references in the code (Student and Course). But do I need 2 relationship in the database? Maybe enough for one? (`Report-to-Course` or `Report-to-Student`). And so I can get the values ​​of both entities from the relationship between them. How such this approach is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "the report is a set of ratings?" Yes

OK, that clears things a little bit. I'm still unceratin as to what exactly are you trying to model, but I'll give it a stab:

[image]

The RATING PK<sup>1</sup> ensures no student can rate the same course more than once. A report is simply a set of ratings.

This structure does *not* ensure that all ratings in the report are related to the same course, nor it enforces the course attendance in any way<sup>2</sup>.

---

*<sup>1</sup> Specifically, the fact that `REPORT_ID` is **outside** the PK, so one rating cannot be part of multiple reports. If you want the opposite, you cannot just include that field in the PK since that would allow for different `VALUE`s - you'll need a proper junction table instead.*

*<sup>2</sup> You might want to forbid a rating of a course by a student that did not attend the course. Let me know how you intend to represent the course attendance and I might have some ideas how to connect that to ratings and reports...*

Comment: O thanks! This's a very fresh and interesting idea! I'm even not thought of that. But it has one drawback. I can't create the `PK of RATING` on only two fields `COURSE_ID` and `STUDENT_ID`. This isn't enough because rating of the same student by the same course can be in multiple reports. I suppose I should also include the REPORT_ID to the `PK of RATING`. I would have been satisfied by this schema. But **why did you write that "include that field in the PK" is bad?** I don't understand. Thanks!

Comment: @Michael Because that would allow different `VALUE`s for the same student/course combination. You don't want to allow a student to rate the same course multiple times (and potentially differently), do you?

Comment: _"to allow a student to rate the same course multiple times (and potentially differently)"_ Yes, it's true. Report has a date. So the same student may have rating on the same subject in another semester. It'll be another report.

Comment: It would be the right to add also `REPORT_ID` to composite `PK of RATING` in that case. It's good solution. Am I right?

Comment: @Michael If you want "per-report" `VALUE` (as opposed to `VALUE` than must be the same for the same student/course combination even when used in multiple reports) then sure, go right ahead and make the `REPORT_ID` part of the `RATING` PK.

Answer (score 0):

Don't include a link to the 'report' table in either the students or courses table. I suggest that you use the following structure:

```
STUDENT
id
forename
surname
dob  
... other fields

LECTURER
id
forename
surname
honorific (Mr/Dr/Professor, etc)
department id
... other fields

COURSE
id
name
duration
credits

SEMESTER
id
course id
lecturer id

RATINGS
semester id
student id
mark
```

This way you can have a course (eg Introduction to Economics) taught by several lecturers at different dates. Students are enrolled for a specific semester and have a mark for that semester. If you want that students have several marks for a given course/semester, then add a date field to the ratings table.

Your reports will generally query the ratings table.

Comment: Shouldn't ratings have a course_id instead of a semester_id ?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt: what if I took economics in winter 12, failed and took it again in spring 13? A course is defined once, but a semester reoccurs.

Comment: Sorry, then I misunderstood the schema - I thought a semester is something like "Winter 12" and a course something like "Algebra, Winter 12" (so there would be a 1:n relationship between semester and course instead of the other way round)

Comment: Yes, I agree with Frank. This relationship is wrong. Report (semester) can have many courses, not one.

Comment: @Michael: So call that table something else like 'instances'. It has to contain the the course id, the lecturer id and a season/date.